# I want to express the below "I have only one of the two" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

The component has two props `A` and `B`.
However, there are no two at the same time. That is, only one is declared.
I think bellow four patterns.In this case,　assume that A and B are boolean value.

1. It's okay

```
const props: XORType = {A: true}
```

2. It's okay

```
const props: XORType = {B: true}
```

3. It's bad

```
const props: XORType = {A: true, B: true}
```

4. It's bad

```
const props: XORType = {}
```

I want to define `XORType`. Please help someone.

Comment: What about `{B:false}` or `{B:false, A:true}`?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova yes, that't right. `{B:false}` is included pattern 2. And, `{B:false, A:true}` is included in pattern 3.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why `{A: boolean, B?:never} | {A?:never, B: boolean}` did not work for you. Can you create a TP playground to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface A {
    a: boolean
    b?: never;
}

interface B {
    b: boolean;
    a?: never;
}

type XorType = A | B;

let c1 : XorType = { a: true }; //ok
let c2 : XorType = { b: true }; //ok
let c3 : XorType = { a: true, b: true} //error
```

ie, `XorType` will not allow to be assigned an object with both `a` and `b` properties if both are `boolean`. Although it will allow to assign

```
let c4 : XorType = { a: true, b: undefined } //ok
```

but not

```
let c5 : XorType = { a: undefined, b: undefined } //error
```

Answer (score 0):

Hows this?

```
const A = false;
const B = true;

type Type1 = {
  A: true;
  B: false;
}

type Type2 = {
  A: false;
  B: true;
};


const myMethod = (props: Type1 | Type2): void => {}

myMethod({A, B})

// TRUE , TRUE === Warning
// FALSE, FALSE === Warning
// TRUE, FALSE === Good
// FALSE, TRUE === Good
```

Comment: this won't allow `myMethod({ A: true})` or `myMethod({B: true})`